# How to bypass 401 error for this api with python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, cookies, http-status-code-401

I download options chain data from this page: https://opstra.definedge.com/optionchain

I found an api to download the json data with python here at https://opstra.definedge.com/api/openinterest/optionchain/free/NIFTY&26MAY2022

All was working fine for few months. Suddenly I started getting a 401 error. How can I bypass the 401 error?

I have a account to authenticate myself against the server.

My previous python code that is not working anymore

```
import requests

sym = "NIFTY"
exp_date = '26MAY2022'

# def oc(sym,exp_date ):
url = "https://opstra.definedge.com/api/openinterest/optionchain/"+sym+'&'+exp_date
headers = { "accept-encoding" : "gzip, deflate, br",
           "accept-language" : "en-US,en;q=0.9",
           "referer": "https://opstra.definedge.com/optionchain",
           "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.136 Safari/537.36"}


response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response)
```

Can anyone help me in getting the data again with python?

Comment: 401 means unauthorized, your credentials might have expired. You should contact the website support or owner.

Comment: I've got `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opstra.definedge.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/openinterest/optionchain/NIFTY&26MAY2022 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fafe793d6a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again')).`

Comment: Don't share your login details